# Does google recaptcha 3 on vuetify really not appear? automatic?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, recaptcha, vuetify.js

I try from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha-v3

https://techformist.com/use-google-recaptcha-in-vue-forms/

It is only displayed in the lower right. The user does not need to check and it is not shown on the input form

[image]

Is the captcha method valid? Because the user does not give a check mark

Answer (score 0):

> There are different versions available in google recaptcha.

In the above question your are using **reCAPTCHA v3**, Its just evaluating the user interaction in pure javascript and returning a score, Instead of having a checkbox "I'm not a robot". That's how version 3 works

I think you are looking for **reCAPTCHA v2 ("I'm not a robot" Checkbox)**

In this version, the user has to **tick box and verify its a human interaction**

> You can use this library to implement the same
>   https://github.com/drozdzynski/vue-grecaptcha

There are still 2 more version in google recaptcha that is

> reCAPTCHA v2 (Android) reCAPTCHA v2 (Invisible reCAPTCHA badge)